# JOSESwift jwe encryption failed to decode in the nimbus server

Tags: ios, swift, jwe, jose

Had anybody used JOSESwift successfully? In my case, decryption in the server failing, probably cannot find the matching private key or wrong with encryption. Getting error 500.

My code is, getting the public keys from a server.

```
keys?.keys?.forEach({ (key) in
                BPLogger.debug("\(key)")
                do {
                    let jwkData = key.toJSONString()?.data(using: .utf8)
                    let rsaKey = try RSAPublicKey(data: jwkData!)
                    BPLogger.log("key components: \(rsaKey.parameters)")
                    BpidCache.shared.joseRsaKey = rsaKey
                    self?.generateParametersJose()
                    completion()                        
                    return
                } catch  {
                    BPLogger.debug("Error: \(error)")
                }
            })
```

The server expected a 'kid' field in the jose header, which was missing in the framework. So I have added it... The backend Java server uses [nimbus](https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt) library.

```
 func generateParametersJose() {
        let rsa = BpidCache.shared.joseRsaKey
        var publicKey: SecKey? = nil
        do {
            publicKey = try rsa?.converted(to: SecKey.self)
        } catch {
            BPLogger.log("\(error)")
        }
        var header = JWEHeader(algorithm: .RSA1_5, encryptionAlgorithm: .A256CBCHS512)
//      header.parameters["kid"] = "1"
        let jwk = MidApi.Model.JWTKey(key: cek);
        let jwkData = try! JSONEncoder().encode(jwk)
        BPLogger.debug("jwkData = \(String(data: jwkData, encoding: .utf8)!)")
        let payload = Payload(jwkData)
        // Encrypter algorithms must match header algorithms.
        guard let encrypter = Encrypter<SecKey>(keyEncryptionAlgorithm: .RSA1_5, encryptionKey: publicKey!, contentEncyptionAlgorithm: .A256CBCHS512) else {
            return
        }
        guard let jwe = try? JWE(header: header, payload: payload, encrypter: encrypter) else {
            BPLogger.error("Falied jwe creation.")
            return
        }

        var comps = jwe.compactSerializedString.components(separatedBy: ".")
        var jweHeader = comps.first
        let data = jweHeader?.base64URLDecode()
        var orgH = try! JSONDecoder().decode(BPJweHeader.self, from: data!)
        orgH.kid = "1"
        let newJson = try! JSONEncoder().encode(orgH).base64URLEncodedString()
        comps[0] = newJson
        let newHeader = comps.joined(separator: ".")
        BPLogger.log("jwe.compactSerializedString = \(newHeader)")
        headers = ["X-Encrypted-Key": newHeader]
//      headers = ["X-Encrypted-Key": jwe.compactSerializedString] // this also fails
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like you're changing the header after encrypting the JWE. Because the header is used as additional authenticated data when encrypting the JWE, changing the header afterwards invalidates the encrypted data. To make it work you have to configure your header before using it in a JWE. Unfortunately, it is currently not possible to set additional parameters in headers due to a bug which is currently being fixed in https://github.com/airsidemobile/JOSESwift/pull/110. Expect a release that fixes this in the next couple of days!

Comment: For a workaround see https://github.com/airsidemobile/JOSESwift/issues/112#issuecomment-426960809

Comment: Yes, thanks. Created a local pod and added the 'kid' param in JweHeader, solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest version of JOSESwift ([1.3.0](https://github.com/airsidemobile/JOSESwift/releases/tag/1.3.0)) contains [a fix](https://github.com/airsidemobile/JOSESwift/pull/110) for the problem that prevented setting additional header parameters.

You can now set the additional header parameters listed in [RFC-7516](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7516#section-4.1). Setting the `"kid"` parameter like you tried to do in your question works like this:

```
var header = JWEHeader(algorithm: .RSA1_5, encryptionAlgorithm: .A256CBCHS512)

header.kid = "1"
```

If you use the framework via CocoaPods, make sure to run `pod repo update` to make sure you install the latest version which contains the fix.